# MVCSitemap - maintaining the ID parameter in sub-pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I've got the following structure to a site:

```
/Products/
    /Details/{ID}
       /Details/Edit/{ID}
```

It's slightly different from the usual /products/edit and /products/details approach most sites have, because the edit link is only available on the Details page.

My problem is [ASP.NET MVCSitemap](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/) doesn't maintain the keys in the sitemap. So when I'm on the edit page it produce a crumbtrail of:

```
<a href="/Products">Products</a>
<a href="/Products/Details">Details</a>
<a href="/Products/Details/Edit/{id}">Edit</a>
```

**instead of the HTML I'm expecting:**

```
<a href="/Products">Products</a>
<a href="/Products/{id}/Details">Details</a>
<a href="/Products/Details/Edit/{id}">Edit</a>
```

Notice that the 2nd link has no key in it. Is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out myself that this is an issue with the current version (1.0.1) - as the example project doesn't render the crumbtrail properly for parent links with Ids. More details [here](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=71990).

Answer (score 0):

New version 2.1.0 may fix this issue. Check http://mvcsitemapprovider.com